# Inkscape - Doubled bezier curves

Tags: inkscape, path, stroke, line-art

I want to have a bezier curve with a double line stroke. The `LinkedOffset` option for paths, when I apply it to an unclosed bezier curve, creates a linked offset object that is closed - ie, it draws a direct line from the end of the curve to the start that I don't want.

Is there another way, or something I'm missing about this closure line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you want, but you maybe you can:

- draw a single line, with a large width (like 5px)
- then convert it to a path (Menu Path -> Stroke to Path),
- then remove the fill color, and set a stroke color,
- reset stroke with to 1px
- and remove the "caps".

[image: Step1]

[image: Step2-3-4]

[image: Step5]

Comment: That's much simpler than the linked offset hack, awesome. I'll have to play with it later, thanks!